# Attribute for ignoring "too many arguments in call to 'func'"

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc

I am creating a light test framework. For my local debugging in linux with gcc and clang, I do not get any complaints for mocking a function that has arguments, but mocking it with no arguments. eg.

> add.c

```c
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

> foo.c

```c
#include "add.h"

int add_2(int a) {
    return add(a, 2);
}
```

Now, in order to mock add. I simply created these macros.

> testframework.h

```c
#define DECLARE_MOCK(type, name)                                               \
  type __var_##name[255];                                                      \
  size_t __var_##name##_inc = 0;                                               \
  size_t __var_##name##_actual = 0;                                            \
  type name() { return (type)__var_##name[__var_##name##_inc++]; }

#define MOCK(name, value) __var_##name[__var_##name##_actual++] = value;
```

This works well on my linux machine. `add(x,y)` requires two arguments, but gcc or clang doesn't complain that the mock will essentially have no arguments passed to it, and works perfectly as a stand in. it's this line here `type name() ...`

Here is the usage. Notice I am mocking add.c capability in this test file.

```c
#include "foo.h"
#include "testframework.h"

DECLARE_MOCK(int, add);


int main() {
  DESCRIBE("things");
  MOCK(add, 2);
  SHOULDB("add", {
    ASSERT(add(0, 2) == 2);
  });
 }
```

The issue comes in on gcc mac, which complains.

> [INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c11 -O3 -o target/things tests/things.c obj/things/lib.o
> tests/things.c:29:57: error: too many arguments in call to 'add' [-Werror]
> SHOULDB("add", { ASSERT(add(0, 2) == 2); });

I would like to keep `-Wall` and `-Werror`, I was hoping there was an attribute I could add to the macro, which is the opposite of sentinel.

Comment: Maybe you should declare it with variable number of arguments? Although that won't work for a function that actually takes no arguments.

Comment: What is `DESCRIBE`?  What is `SHOULDB`?  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @dbush I'm not so sure that's necessary, I could remove the code, and just ask the question. The code is for some context, incase I have an x y problem, which Baramar was able to provide a work around.

Comment: @Barmar that actually worked. you can put an answer if you would like the points. adding `type name(__attribute__((unused)) int i, ...) {`  Worked for both scenarios.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer with all the details filled in. I guess you could have another `MOCK_VOID()` for no-argument functions.

Comment: @Barmar I'm saying adding the __attribute__((unused)) satiated no argument functions.

Comment: unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I think that just prevents warning about not using the argument in the function body, it has nothing to do with the callers. If you declare a function `f(int i, ...)` and then call it `f()` you should get an error about too few arguments.